# Find $\int (e^{2x}+e^{3x})^\frac{1}{2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int (e^{2x}+e^{3x})^\frac{1}{2}dx$$
I'm not sure what substitution I'm supposed to make here. Can someone help?

Comment: Note that $\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(e^{2x}+e^{3x}=\left(e^x\right)^2+\left(e^x\right)^3\right)$, this suggests a substitution.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int \sqrt{e^{2x}+e^{3x}}dx = \int e^x\sqrt{1+e^x}dx  $$ Let $ u \equiv e^x+1$. So we have $$ \int \sqrt{u}du = \frac{2\sqrt{e^x+1}^3}{3} + C $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\int (e^{2x}+e^{3x})^\frac{1}{2}dx=\int e^x \sqrt{e^x+1} dx$$